# Is it possible to create jsbin code with service worker?

Tags: service-worker, jsbin

In JSBin, I don't see an option to add service worker. Is it possible? Or, is there any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to put together an example/demo that registers your own service worker using JSBin.

In terms of other options, what I tend to do is use GitHub's Gists to store my HTML and service worker JavaScript, and then use RawGit to serve the resources. RawGit gives you HTTPS plus proper `Content-Type` headers, both of which are necessary in order to register a service worker.

Here's an example of [a Gist](https://gist.github.com/jeffposnick/da9782fd96514b8fdf5e07a64580d431) that uses this setup.

You need to get the ["Raw" URL for your HTML](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jeffposnick/da9782fd96514b8fdf5e07a64580d431/raw/2c50ccfbf19d0df548ae5a39c7eba71caaac86e4/index.html) (click on the "Raw" button in the Gist interface), and then paste that URL into https://rawgit.com/. When registering your service worker from your HTML, always use a relative URL (like `navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js');`), and include the code for your service worker in another file that's part of the same Gist.

You'll end up [with a URL served by RawGit](https://rawgit.com/jeffposnick/da9782fd96514b8fdf5e07a64580d431/raw/2c50ccfbf19d0df548ae5a39c7eba71caaac86e4/index.html) that will let you access your HTML and can register and use your service worker file.